# Log in to embedded webbrowser

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control

I figured out how to automate a login using vba, but I would like to do the same with an embedded webbrowser. I have tried various methods found online, but am not having success.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have currently. I'd like to make it work on "sheet1.webbrowser1"

```
Dim HTMLDoc As Object
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Website_Login_Test()

Dim oHTML_Element As Object
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "http://example.com/login.action?os_destination=%2Fhomepage.action"

Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.Navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.os_username.Value = "this"
HTMLDoc.all.os_password.Value = "this"

HTMLDoc.all.os_cookie.Click
HTMLDoc.all.login.Click

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim oBrowser As Object
Set oBrowser = Sheet1.WebBrowser1
oBrowser.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's easy enough.